# Task Scheduler onstart process not listening on port

Tags: c#, windows, taskscheduler

I'm trying to make script that will start needed processes every time each machine will reset for any reason. (Windows Server 2016 core)

I began by using windows Task Scheduler, that was running a bat file on startup as Administrator. Problem that I noticed is that processes from bat are not run as Administrator, but I needed them to be.

Then I used Task Scheduler again, making a task for each process so I could run them with adequate privileges, but running it on startup the process port doesn't appear in netstat, making me believe it is not working properly.

What else could I try to make sure the processes will listen on given ports (12001) when run on system startup?

Comment: Are you the author of these processes? Because it sounds like what you need is for them to run as *services*. The infrastructure for services already exists to start them automatically on system startup, and they can run under arbitrary accounts (or various system accounts with varying amounts of power).

Comment: No I'm not the author of those processes, all this software is from our recently closed facility and we are trying to prepare temporary solution. We planned to turn them into services but it might take longer than expected as there are lots of those processes. Thank you for answering :)